# Installing play framework windows vista

Tags: playframework

I am installing the play framework latest version on windows vista.
After running the activator script file, everything was running smoothly for a while until this:

```
[warn] e.m.m.MimeDetectorRegistry - MimeDetector [eu.medsea.mimeutil.detector.Ma
gicMimeMimeDetector] will not be registered as a MimeDetector with this name is
already registered.
```

If you need more information as to where it went wrong, this is a few more lines:

```
:: retrieving :: org.scala-sbt#boot-app
        confs: [default]
        81 artifacts copied, 0 already retrieved (66866kB/1311ms)
FOUND REPO = activator-local @ file:////C:/Program%20Files/activator-1.2.10-mini
mal/repository
Play server process ID is 5824
[info] play - Application started (Prod)
[info] play - Listening for HTTP on /127.0.0.1:8888
[info] a.e.s.Slf4jLogger - Slf4jLogger started
[INFO] [09/17/2014 15:56:03.036] [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5] [akka
://default/user/home-socket-1] Firing up web socket
[warn] e.m.m.MimeDetectorRegistry - MimeDetector [eu.medsea.mimeutil.detector.Ma
gicMimeMimeDetector] will not be registered as a MimeDetector with this name is
already registered.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the MimeDetector source, I believe you can safely ignore this warning.

```
/**
 * Use the fully qualified name of a MimeDetector and try to instantiate it if
 * it's not already registered. If it's already registered then log a warning and
 * return the already registered MimeDetector
 * @param mimeDetector
 * @return MimeDetector registered under this name. Returns null if an exception occurs
 */
MimeDetector registerMimeDetector(final String mimeDetector) {
    if(mimeDetectors.containsKey(mimeDetector)) {
        log.warn("MimeDetector [" + mimeDetector + "] will not be registered as a MimeDetector with this name is already registered.");
        return (MimeDetector)mimeDetectors.get(mimeDetector);
    }
```

I suspect that more than one dependency is loading MimeDetector, so you can look into your dependencies if you'd like to find the source.

But since MimeDetector is aware of this and is refusing to be instantiated twice -- instead returning the already existing instance -- I wouldn't expect any issues.